# Arithmetic progressions with coprime differences

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have finite number $n \geqslant 2$ of arithmetic progressions $\{x \equiv  r_1 \pmod {d_1}\}, \ldots ,\{ x \equiv r_n \pmod {d_n}\}$ such that $\gcd(d_1, \ldots, d_n) = 1.$

Is true that some pair of them has nonempty intersection? (I think, it's true).

Comment: 1(6),4(10),5(15). (No point in trying to make it an answer: the system will declare it "trivial" and convert it into a comment anyway. Not that I would be able to offer it a good counterargument...)

Comment: @fedja If you wrap that in two or three sentences explaining the point, the system will not auto-convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: the three congruences $x\equiv 0\pmod{6}$, $x\equiv 1\pmod{10}$, $x\equiv 2\pmod{15}$.

One can produce similar counterexamples using any three distinct primes $p,q,r$ instead of $2,3,5$.

**Remark:** I notice that fedja gave a very similar counterexample in a comment.

Comment: Or, in fact, any three pairwise relatively prime numbers...